# How can I resolve this loop in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm working in a c# desktop application, using visual studio 2010.
I want to read each record and load a "street name dictionary" for each US state.
For example, I read first record (id=1), so I load AlabamaDictionary.txt because this record it is from Alabama State, after load it, start another process like address standardizations, etc. When this process it is finished, I read next record (id=2) and I've to check if "State" is the same, if is the same state than before, I don't need to load again AlabamaDictionary.txt because it is load it yet, start another process like address standardizations. When this process it is finished, I read next record (id=3) which is from "Arizona". Here state change so I need to load Arizona.txt and start again another address standardizations process, etc...
my problem is to change dictionary, to check when it is change.

```
Records
    "id" | "address"       | "state"
    1    |100 Elm St       | Alabama
    2    |300 Trawick St   | Alabama
    3    |50023 N 51st Ave | Arizona
```

I Have next loop
Code:
DataTable records;

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.Rows.Count; i++)
{
string address = records.Rows[i][1].ToString(); 
string  state = records.Rows[i][2].ToString();
streetDictionary = state + ".txt";
if(File.Exists(streetDictionary))
{
//Here I need to identify state change, 
//so if state change , to use another dictionary and load it, 
//but if don't change it (state), I need to use the same dictionary 
//(if is load it yet)
 LoadStreetDictionary(streetDictionary);

//Process Address Standardization
StreetNameStandardization(address)
}
}
```

Please, How can i do this loop?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your latest state in the variable, and add checking per iteration

```
string prevState = string.Empty;
   for (int i = 0; i < records.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        string address = records.Rows[i][1].ToString(); 
        string  state = records.Rows[i][2].ToString();

    if (!state.Equals(prevSate))
    {
        streetDictionary = state + ".txt";
        if(File.Exists(streetDictionary))
        {
            //Here I need to identify state change, 
            //so if state change , to use another dictionary and load it, 
            //but if don't change it (state), I need to use the same dictionary 
            //(if is load it yet)
            LoadStreetDictionary(streetDictionary);
        }


     }

     //Process Address Standardization
     StreetNameStandardization(address)
     prevState = state; //Assigned to latest value
    }
```

Edit : Always execute standardization function.

Comment: Thanks Maku but dont work, because if I've first record (id=1 state=Alabama") it work fine, loading alabama.txt, but in the next record (id=2 state=Alabama") if (!state.Equals(prevSate)) dont let in, and I need to in, using same dictionary previously load it (not loading again)

Comment: sorry i miss this part "start another process like address standardizations. ". I'd updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

define a variable before your loop...

```
string lastState="";
```

then enclose the reading of the dictionary in a check to see if you are still on the same state

```
if (!state.equals(lastState))
{
    // read the dictionary here

    // then...
    lastState = state;
}
// check your address here
StreetAddressStandardization();
```

Comment: Thanks Gilchrist but dont work, because if I've first record (id=1 state=Alabama") it work fine, loading alabama.txt, but in the next record (id=2 state=Alabama") if (!state.Equals(prevSate)) dont let in, and I need to in, using same dictionary previously load it (not loading again)

Comment: But that is the whole point, you don't "let in" to read the dictionary, on the second one, because it is already read.  But you still do the StreetNameStandardization because that is outside of the if {} statement.

Comment: Will only work if records are sorted by state, which is not obvious from the code.

Comment: @Bond - in his text, the OP specifies that is what he wants to do, not read the dictionary if the state is the same as the last one, but read it when the state changes.

Answer (score 2):

I hope im understanding your request properly.

```
String lastState = "";
for (int i = 0; i < records.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string address = records.Rows[i][1].ToString(); 
    string  state = records.Rows[i][2].ToString();
    streetDictionary = state + ".txt";
    if(File.Exists(streetDictionary))
    {
        if (currentState != state)
            LoadStreetDictionary(streetDictionary);
        lastState = state;

        //Process Address Standardization
        StreetNameStandardization(address)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, but dont work, because if I read first record (id=1 state=Alabama") it work fine, loading alabama.txt, but in the next record (id=2 state=Alabama")  dont work because load dictionary for every record, and I need load just one time, only load a new dictionary when state change. Thank you very much! And I'm sorry for my bad english